# Блок не заезжает обратно

Tags: jquery, html

Подскажите, в чем у меня ошибка? Блок должен выехать, когда скролл больше 200 и заехать, когда он меньше. У меня он выезжает нормально, а вот заехать не хочет (только через некоторое время заезжает (когда между вкладками прыгать начинаю)).

Хотелось бы получить ответ почему не работает (а не код), что я тут забыл (если, конечно, не весь код переделывать надо) и почему оно работает только "через время".

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='reset.css'>

    <script type="text/javascript" src='scripts/qwe.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="scripts/jquery.dimensions.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){  
        $(window).scroll(function () { 
            var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
            if(scroll >= 200){
                $('#text').animate({ 'left' : '0' }, 2000 );

            } else {
                if ($('#text').position().left > -400){
                    $('#text').animate({ 'left' : '-400' }, 2000 );
                    console.log(scroll);
                }   
            }
        });
      });  
</script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
          height: 2000px;
          background: #FFA0FF;
        }
        #text {
            width: 400px;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: -400px;
            display: block;
            border: 1px dashed red;
        }
        hr {
margin-top: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="menu"></div> 
        <hr/> 
        <div id="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet     
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: По моему не очень хорошая идея на событие скрол инициализироавть анимейты - мне кажеться их будет слишком много, а Вам явно нужен один

Comment: я вот [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/118790/помогите-перевести-в-jquery) даже описал как этого добиться

Comment: во! сработало - спасибо 

Как-то о флаге не подумал